# PHP Mailer asynchronous with symfony

Tags: php, multithreading, symfony, asynchronous, phpmailer

I developed a system where each order status send an email to customer, but every time this email spend between 5-15 seconds to send, because this lock new requests from that user in website until finish the sending, so to try solve this I' ve been saving these emails in database for each 40 seconds. Then I send an ajax request to server to send these emails together, but php still block new requests until the emails finish, I read that i need to developer something like multi-thread, but I 'm use symfony 5.4 and this is being more complex than I thought, I tried to use "curl_multi" to request itself in other endpoint to send these emails but it doesn't work as well

phpmailer
Symfony 5.4.27
Php 8.2

Comment: 1. If an email takes longer than a second to send, that is a problem that needs to be solved on its own. 2. "php still block new requests until the emails finish" either your script is contending for a lock on the session file, or you're trying to use `php -S` in production.

Comment: The best way to make email submission really fast is to install a local mail server to use a a relay, then make your email script send to localhost instead of some distant server. I have no problem using this approach to send over 600 messages/sec using PHPMailer. SMTP is very chatty and has long timeouts, so it's unsuited to sending during HTTP request processing, though many ignore that. Aside from that, an asynchronous queuing approach in PHP will achieve much the same, though it will require far more programming for you to implement something that mail servers do (better) out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good case for making use of [Symfony's Messenger component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html). Messenger does pretty much exactly what you're trying to accomplish. It allows you to put messages (tasks) into a queue which are handled asynchronously outside of the regular request -> response cycle. The basic idea of how you use it is:

- define a message class that stores some data. In your case probably just the order ID would be enough.
- define a message handler with an `__invoke()` method that takes in a message as its only parameter. In your case, this is where you'd write the logic to send the email to the customer.
- in a controller or service, create and dispatch the message via the `MessageBusInterface`.
- configure a transport that tells Symfony to handle your messages asynchronously.
- run the consumer process which will watch for new messages in the queue and perform the actions on them that you defined in the handler.

### A note on the terminology

Keep in mind that the term *message* in this context isn't referring to email or anything like that -- it's a part of the [command bus design pattern](https://matthiasnoback.nl/tags/command%20bus/) (aka a message bus).

### References

- [Symfony - Messenger: Sync & Queued Message Handling](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#transports-async-queued-messages)
- [Symfony - The Messenger Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/messenger.html)